# Laravel Eloquent: How to form "Select distinct with count" request?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to form a very simple mySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name`, 
                Count(*) AS count 
FROM   users 
WHERE  id > 1 
GROUP  BY `name`;
```

I try this one:

```
$users = User::where('id', '>', '1')
                ->distinct('name')
                ->count();
```

Result is 52 :( 
How to fix it?

Comment: isn't 52 the correct answer ? What are you expecting as a result ?

Comment: @iizno you can see that do I expect in my SQL request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods):

```php
$users = User::selectRaw('distinct `name`')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as count')
    ->where('id', '>', 1)
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

Which will perform the following query:

```sql
select
    distinct `name`,
    count(*) as count
from `users`
where
    `id` > 1
group by `name`
```

Comment: It works! Appreciate your support. Looks like your are top expert in Laravel. Wish you good luck in all of  your projects!